# What does the result of apply method mean in sklearn GradientBoostingClassifier

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I want get the leaf in GradientBoostingClassifier model, and I'm ambiguous the result of the `apply` method, my code is in below:

```
df = pd.read_csv("iris.data", header=None, names=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'label'])
df['label'] = df['label'].map(lambda x: 0 if x=="Iris-setosa" else 1 if x=="Iris-versicolor" else 2)
X = df[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']].values
y = df['label'].values

X_train = X[:120]
y_train = y[:120]

gbt = GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=2, max_depth=4)
gbt.fit(X_train, y_train)

x_leaf = gbt.apply(X_train)
print(x_leaf)
```

and I get the `x_leaf` result:

```
[[[ 5.  1.  3.]
  [ 4.  1.  5.]]

 [[ 2.  1.  3.]
  [ 2.  1.  5.]]

 [[ 2.  1.  3.]
  [ 2.  1.  5.]]

 [[ 2.  1.  3.]
  [ 2.  1.  5.]]

 [[ 2.  1.  3.]
  [ 4.  1.  5.]]

 [[ 7.  1.  3.]
  [ 4.  1.  5.]]

 [[ 2.  1.  3.]
  [ 2.  1.  5.]]

 [[ 2.  1.  3.]
  [ 2.  1.  5.]]

 [[ 2.  1.  3.]
  [ 2.  1.  5.]]

 [[ 2.  1.  3.]
  [ 2.  1.  5.]]
 ...    ...]
```

I'm wonder why `x_leaf[:, :, 0]` as the leaf index but not other columns, you see there are three columns in the `x_leaf`. How can I understand it?

Answer (score 1):

From scikit-learn documentation:

> X_leaves : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_estimators, n_classes)
> For each datapoint x in X and for each tree in the ensemble,
> return the index of the leaf x ends up in each estimator.
> In the case of binary classification n_classes is 1.

So for example, x_leaf[100, 2, 1] will return the index of the leaf that the sample in row 100 end up in the second estimator for the prediction of the label '1'.

Note that the leaf value is bounded to 2**(max_depth + 1).

Comment: I want to know why the only select the first column as the leaf index as the scikit-learn official example [gbdt+lr model](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_feature_transformation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-ensemble-plot-feature-transformation-py) does.

Comment: In their example they use binary classification so n_classes =1. In this case the shape of x_leaf is (80000, 10, 1) . So by slicing x_leaf[:, :, 0] they get a matrix where the i, j item is the index of the leaf that row i ends up i in the j estimator where predicting if sample i is positive.